# Congruence of angles with vertex at Fermat-Torricelli point through any two vertices

Tags: euclidean-geometry

At the following website, $\angle{ARF} \cong \angle{ABF}$ is asserted.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point#Construction

(See section labeled Location of X(13).)  The Inscribed-Angle Theorem is tacitly used.  $A$, $B$, and $R$ are, by definition, points on the same circle. Why is F another point on the circle?

Answer (score 3):

Equipped with which facts do you want to start? The angles are supplementary: $\angle ARB = 60^{\circ}$ and $\angle AFB = 120^{\circ}$.

For a quadrilateral, when an opposing pair of angles add up to $\pi$, it is cyclic.

---

Assume you agree to start with the definition of a Fermat point as constructing equilateral triangles for each of the sides.

In the wikipedia figure shown below, compare the red $\color{red}{\triangle ARC}$ and the blue $\color{blue}{\triangle ABQ}$.

We have the short side matching: $\color{red}{\overline{AR}} = \color{blue}{\overline{AB}}$ because of the equilateral triangle of the side $\overline{AB}$. Similarly, we have the long side matching $\color{red}{\overline{AC}} = \color{blue}{\overline{AQ}}$ due to the equilateral triangle of the side $\overline{AC}$.

[image]

Further, we have $\color{red}{\angle RAC} = \frac{\pi}3 + \angle BAC = \color{blue}{\angle BAQ}$

Thus by side-angle-side we have the congruence between $\color{red}{\triangle ARC} \cong \color{blue}{\triangle ABQ}$

Now, since the two triangles share a vertex, point $A$, we see that $\color{blue}{\triangle ABQ}$ can be obtained by rotating $\color{red}{\triangle ARC}$, counter-clockwise by $\frac{\pi}3$ (or equivalently clockwise by $\frac{2\pi}3$.

That is, $\angle RFB = \frac{\pi}3$, which is half of our desired $\angle AFB$.

The other half comes from the same analysis on $\triangle ABP \cong \triangle RBC$, establishing the $\frac{\pi}3$ rotational relation between $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{RC}$.

Comment: Why is the measure of $\angle{AFB}$ equal to $120^{\circ}$?

Comment: By the construction of the equilateral triangles, we can show that the relevant lines are rotated by $2\pi/3$. Literally this is the first thing one learns about the Fermat point (before knowing the more modern notion of X13 and all that)

Comment: I am looking for a careful explanation.

Comment: @Adelyn I've added the standard content. See if this is what you want. BTW you can remove the earlier comments that are redundant now.

Comment: I understand your argument. The image on the website is small; I should have coded a diagram for it in `TikZ`.

Comment: @Adelyn Well just let me do a screen grab. You can click on the .svg and use the zoom with your browser.

Comment: OK.  I agree that having a diagram in the post would be convenient.

Comment: I will encode a diagram for it tomorrow.  I can put the code as a response.  Do you know how to include a `pdf` file in a post?

Comment: Do you have a reference that would explain that the Fermat point that you defined is the point in the triangle that minimizes the sum of the distances between it and the vertices of the triangle?

Comment: @Adelyn (1) StackExchange doesn't support inserting documents in the posts other than images under 2Mb. (2) For a advanced treatment [maybe this](http://www.web.pdx.edu/~mnn3/FT.pdf) that deals with polygons in general. If you want an undergrad lower division material that is still credible, then seriously textbooks are the way to go.

Comment: @Adelyn Textbooks on geometry ... off the top of my head I cannot point to. For something online, maybe like an [academic paper for educators and students like this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0020739X.2014.979894) or [that](https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/an-advanced-calculus-approach-to-finding-the-fermat-point). The former can be accessed via [3rd party link](http://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1080/0020739X.2014.979894) (umm .... low key) , and the latter is from MAA.org which itself is a good source.

Comment: I did read the first link you suggested. It does explain - rigorously explain - that the Fermat-Torricelli point is a point of intersection of the three line segments in the Torricelli configuration from a given triangle. It verifies that the measure of the three angles formed from two vertices of the given triangle and the Fermat-Torricelli point is $120^{\circ}$. It verifies that the Fermat-Torricelli point is on the circles circumscribing the three equilateral triangles, too.

Comment: Geometry Revisited by Coxeter and Greitzer has a terse discussion of it, too.